# Which is better in flutter Bloc to initialize the api class inside the bloc class or pass it as a required param through the blockprovider

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

I have a simple bloc app that fetches data from api now which way is better

1. to initialize the api class inside a method in the bloc class or
2. to pass it as a required parameter through the bloc class constructer and initialize it in the blocprovider

example 1

```
class WeatherBloc *** {
WeatherBloc() : super(**){
   on some event {
final rep = ApiService() <- Here
}
}

}
```

example 2

```
  class WeatherBloc extends ***{
Weatherbloc(required api) : super(**)
final ApiService api; 

******
now on Blockprovider(
create: WeatherBloc(ApiService())
)



}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's better to pass it, so you can test the bloc by passing a mock API class
and you can make it optional and initialize it inside the bloc if it came with null if you don't want to make a fuss in the BlocProviders